# How can i place 2 divs next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I try to put 2 divs next to eachother but somehow it places them under eachother.

I have looked it up on this forum and copied the css code for it but it still wont work, i think it has something to do with my php code i use in it.

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <header>
<nav>
    <p><a href="index.php"><img src="img/handboeklogo.png"></a></p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Checklist</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Desktops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitoren</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Handboek</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Desktops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitoren</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mobiele Telefoons</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Classificatielijst</a><ul>
                <li><a href="#">Desktops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitoren</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mobiele Telefoons</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


<form class='logout' method='POST' action=''>
        <button type='submit' name='logoutSubmit'>Logout</button>
    </form>
</nav>
</header>
<br><br>


<div id='maindiv'><div id='first'>





<form method='POST' action=''>
            <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='1'> 
            <input type='hidden' name='date' value='2019-07-02'> 
            <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
            <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'> Comment </button>
        </form></div>

<div id='second'>



<form method='POST' action=''>
            <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='1'> 
            <input type='hidden' name='date' value='2019-07-02'> 
            <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
            <button type='submit' name='Generalcommentsubmit'> Comment </button>
        </form></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    background-color: #edf0f2;
}

textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 630px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #5bb112;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    resize: none;
}

.Changelog {
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 800px;
}

.logout {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 680px;
}

.login {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 330px;
}
/*
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #5bb112;
    border: none;
    color: #e2e2e2;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.comment-box {
    width: 630px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #5bb112;
    margin-top: 8px;
    align-content: left;
}

.comment-box p {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #282828;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.edit-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 3px;
}

.edit-form button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #282828;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.edit-form button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.delete-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 58px;
}

.delete-form button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #282828;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.delete-form button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #343131;
}

header nav p {
    font-family: arial;
    color: #b3b3b3;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 55px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

header nav ul {
    float: left;
    z-index: 2;
}

header nav ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #b3b3b3;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 21px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #343131;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    padding: 8px;
}

header nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

header nav ul li ul li  {
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

header nav ul li ul li a {
    padding: 9px 14px;
}

header nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #343131;
}

header nav p img {
    width: 210px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


header nav ul li a:hover {opacity: 1}

header nav ul li a {
    background-color: #343131;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

i {
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  }

/*-------Changelog---------*/

#maindiv {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#first {
    width: auto;
    float:left;

}
#second {
    float: left; 
}
```

I would like to place the divs next to eachother so i get 2 comment sections next to eachother.

Comment: You should provide info from your html page (inspect cntrl + u)

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum verifiable example to reproduce your current scenario?

Comment: the first list with code is my html page

Comment: Not relevant to PHP

Comment: @vivek_23 i removed the php tag, i thought the code doesnt work bc i have php code in it that connects with my local database

Comment: @Basickz Ok, you could post the exact HTML you get when you run this code, for us to better understand your issue.

Comment: `display:inline-block` works

Comment: @vivek_23 im sorry if i dont understand you (im new to asking questions about code on a forum) but you want me to post my whole index code?

Comment: @Basickz Yes in a way. First execute your whole index code on your localhost, press Ctrl + U, copy the whole HTML + CSS code from your browser and paste it here with indendation(available in markdown).

Comment: Give the display inline block property to #first, #second

Comment: @vivek_23 i updated the code, i cant find the CSS code when i press CTRL+U

Comment: @Basickz Because have an external stylesheet => `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`. Click that URL on Ctrl U and press the link to get the CSS.

Comment: @vivek_23i updated it with the CSS code now, thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place 2 divs near eachother wrap them in another div and set display to 'flex'

```
<div id="maindiv'>
   <div id='first'>
      //content here
   </div>
   <div id='second'>
      //content here
   </div>
</div>
```

in css

```
#maindiv {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#first {
  width: 300px;
}
#second {

}
```

Comment: do i still have to use the `overflow` and `float` tags?

Comment: no you dont have to use them. the default for flex is flex-direction: row, which means it will place the divs near eachother, you dont need float anymore.

Answer (score 0):

From your current code I could just guess that problem is with display, try this

```
#maindiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: still doesnt change anything, i have other css code but that is not related to these 3 divs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` as `div` element `display` is set to `block` by default

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

</div>
<div class="parent">

</div>
<div class="parent">

</div>
<div class="parent">

</div>
<div class="parent">

</div>
<div class="parent">

</div>
<div class="parent">

</div>
<div class="parent">

</div>
```

Comment: this works! thank you so much!! i was struggling with this for over 5 hours now

Comment: @Basickz please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you. To accept answer,you need to click on the tick mark below upvote of my answer. it will turn into green if you accept it.Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```css
#first, #second, #maindiv{
  display: inline-block;
}
#maindiv {
   width: 500px;
}
#first {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id='maindiv'>
  <div id='first'>first</div>
  <div id='second'>second</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If i use the `inline-block` on all of the divs it will place them under eachother

Comment: first and second are inside maindiv, one next to each other. if you run the snippet you can see it works

Comment: i do the same as you posted here, but i will place them under eachother, the `display:flex; ` tag is working for me, but thanks for taking the time anyway

Comment: I see you updated the code. I think it was because of  the textarea field.  I tried the full code on codepen. if you add `textarea{width: 100%;}` it fixes it. (without flex).